# Searching a Oracle table for a value

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a Oracle table that has nearly 150k records and 65 columns. There is a requirement from my customer that They need to search the whole table with a single search value and that too can be wildcard search.

And the worst part is that i am using php language to do that.

So i have constructed a query which has all 65 columns to search for a single string value.

Sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>
WHERE (col1 || col2 || col3 ... || col65) LIKE '%<SEARCH_VALUE>%'
```

The query is giving output for some fields and sometimes it is failing if we pass some address related fields.

On some scenario, particularly with wild card type search and if it is outputting  more than 1000 rows.

I have done these test using php language. but at the same when i try to execute the query using SQL Developer. It is giving results all the time. So i got confused.

And more over the Oracle server that i am trying to access is an external server and it is not within our environment.

Please suggest me how to implement this feature or idea and i really appreciate your assistant.

Comment: If you aren't using wildcards I think you could do a `WHERE :search IN (col1, col2, col3, ..., col65)`. With wildcards I think you'll need another approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle 11g, you may add a virtual column to the table

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> ADD
SEARCH_COLUMN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (col1 || ' ' || col2 || ' ' || col3 ... ||   col65);
```

Then create an index on the newly created virtual column. The index will store the concatenated string value of all 65 columns. You will not have to change any queries in your application as Oracle will automatically calculate the value of the virtual column with the values of other 65 columns.

Then you can just  use the index virtual column for your searches

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>
WHERE SEARCH_COLUMN LIKE '%<SEARCH_VALUE>%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a pretty horrible design. One problem that comes to mind is shown in the example below

```
col1   col2
===========
ABC    DEF
CDX    ZZZ
```

If your search condition is "CD", both of these rows will match, since you are searching on the concatenation of all columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this trick to search across columns  And i know that the solution is slow.

```
create table test_example as  select * from user_objects where rownum <= 1000;

select t2.* from 
 xmltable('for $i in ora:view("test_example")/ROW
           where fn:exists($i/*[contains(.,$var_text_to_serach)])
           return $i' passing 'change_here' as "var_text_to_serach" columns id varchar(100) path 'OBJECT_ID') t1
     join test_example t2 on t1.id  = t2. OBJECT_ID
;
```

`ora:view` - allows to query tables within xquery expression. Function creates xml-s from table rows.

`xmltable` -  allows to map xquery-xml result to relational model.

`FLWOR expresion` - inside xmltable i'm using `FLWOR expresion` it is acronym from words FOR, LET, WHERE, ORDER, RETURN

`fn:exists($i/*[contains(.,$var_text_to_serach)])` - check if any of columns contains pattern.

`columns id varchar(100) path 'OBJECT_ID'` extract id column from XML. In my example OBJECT_ID is uniquer value in table.

`passing 'change_here' as "var_text_to_serach"` - "change_here" is text to search

to use this example you have to change test_example to your table, and take care about join condition and .

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a user defined data store to create a text index on all of the columns and then search with the contains operator..

Sonething like this

```
 begin
   begin
     ctx_ddl.drop_preference('mymcds');
   exception
     when others then
     null;
  end;
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('mymcds', 'multi_column_datastore');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mymcds', 'columns', 'NAME, POI_STREET_NAME,    
                                              POI_CITY, POI_POSTCODE, ACTUAL_ADDRESS');
end;
/
create index ADDRESS_SEARCH_IDX 
         on MAP_POI(NAME)
            indextype is ctxsys.context
            parameters ('datastore mymcds section group     ctxsys.auto_section_group')
/
```

A search with contains(NAME,'Foo') should search all the columns indexed.